# Find android adb command from logcat

Tags: android, adb, logcat, vnc-server

I hope anyone can help me. I am using `VNC server` on an `Android` stick on which I am developing, because I don't want it to be connected with a display at all time. The problem is that now and then the `VNC` app force closes. Without a display i am forced to restart the whole stick since it auto starts. Now my question, is it possible to restart the `VNC` server from `adb`?

The `log cat` at restart looks like this:

```
02-28 19:27:32.958: I/ActivityManager(270): Start proc com.schumi.vncs for broadcast com.schumi.vncs/.StartServiceAtBootReceiver: pid=1149 uid=10075 gids={3003, 1028}
02-28 19:27:33.138: V/VNCserver(1149): copy -> /data/data/com.schumi.vncs/files/android_vncs
02-28 19:27:33.328: V/VNCserver(1149): Starting /data/data/com.schumi.vncs/files/android_vncs -p 0987654321 -r 0 -s 100 -P 5901   -i enable  
02-28 19:37:40.388: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.schumi.vncs.ServerManager$SocketListener.run(ServerManager.java:283)
02-28 19:37:43.228: I/ActivityManager(270): Process com.schumi.vncs (pid 1149) has died.
```

The `Android Manifest` of the `VNC Server` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="12"
android:versionName="1.0.5"
package="com.schumi.vncs">
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<application
    android:label="@2131165185"
    android:icon="@2130837514"
    android:name="MainApplication">
    <activity
        android:label="@2131165185"
        android:icon="@2130837514"
        android:name=".VNC_serverActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.schumi.vncs.ACTIVITY_UPDATE"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Settings"/>
    <activity
        android:name="Status"/>
    <activity
        android:name="Donate"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <service
        android:name=".ServerManager">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.schumi.vncs.ServerManager"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        android:name=".StartServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.schumi.vncs.BillingService"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.schumi.vncs.BillingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY"/>
            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE"/>
            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
</manifest>
```

Could anyone please help me, it would be much more convenient to execute a batch file rather than restart the whole device

Regards Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It was actually quite simple.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.schumi.vncs/.StartServiceAtBootReceiver
```